# Chrome Extension - URL Retrieval Asynchronous Callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

I don't quite understand how to use the chrome query function.

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
var url = (tabs[0].url)
```

});

I am simply trying to save the value of the url of the currently open tab. Normally when I do this I get an error cannot read property of undefined and I realize I need to call this function asynchronously but I don't really understand how to do so. What is the other callback function supposed to do in this case and how do I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read about all the parameters for the `chrome.tabs.query` [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

By not entering any parameters you can get all chrome tab URLs like so:

```
chrome.tabs.query({},function(tabs){
    tabs.forEach(function(tab){
        console.log(tab.url);
    });
});
```

Note that for using some of those you will need to have `"tabs"` permission inside your manifest.